# Basin Lock Nut Leaking

Tags: leak

So I bought some new taps as the old tap corroded in the middle and snapped so it needed to go.

I took the old ones off which never leaked before and popped the new ones on.

Replacing the washers, but keeping the existing lock nut.

[image: Lock Nut Leak]

Now on the hot tap only, the nut as in the picture has started leaking. Using a basin wrench I have tightened it to it's absolute maximum and it hasn't made a different at all. What are the suggestions here? Do I need to get a new nut? If so how the hell do I get it off?

Comment: Does this supply line have a shut off valve lower down the pipe?

Comment: A little update, it does have a shut valve. Only issue now is that with all the tinkering around even the shut valve area is leaking so I think I am going to have to replace the old pipe work :( I tries using a specific tape around the tap, but that didn't make a difference. I think with it poked about so much I have probably just damaged the old pipe more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to shut off the main water supply going to the house, open a faucet or hose bib that is lower than the area you will cut the pipe. Before you cut the pipe pick up on new supply tubes and [this type](http://www.homedepot.com/p/SharkBite-1-2-in-Chrome-Plated-Brass-Push-to-Connect-x-3-8-in-O-D-Compression-Quarter-Turn-Straight-Stop-Valve-23037-0000LF/202270613) of new valve for under the sink. Replace both while you are at it. This is presuming the pipe coming in is 1/2"

Follow the instructions for installation!!!!

Get 2 new [supply lines](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Homewerks-Worldwide-3-8-in-OD-x-1-2-in-IPS-x-30-in-Faucet-Supply-Line-Braided-Stainless-Steel-7223-30-38-2/203082363) these are 30" you may not need ones that long.

Hook em on up!!